# how to add outline and reflection to water mesh?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, fluid-simulation

So yesterday I saw this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0g5bROk9Hvc , and I tried to make the same thing.[image: My attempt for this scene]

The thing that got me confused is how to add the outline for the water mesh and the reflection in the youtube video

[image: The water that i try to imitate]

I already try to make a simple outline with solidify modifier and flipping normals but doesnt work because the water mesh is just a single plane. any suggestion about how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

[image: River]

What I did, was take a Voronai Texture, stretched out with a mapping node and clamped with a ColorRamp, to make the small "streaks" in the water.

[image: RiverDots]

To make the surface of the water (and the detailed reflection), I used a Noise Texture, softened with a MixRGB Node (mixed with white) and plugged into the height input of a Bump Node. This gives the appearance of small ripples.

[image: RiverRipples]

Lastly, to make the "edge outline", I used a Wave Texture, scaled down so it's only one band and then I clamped it with a ColorRamp as well, so it leaves thin white borders on the plane. I then use this as a mask factor for where the "border color" will be mixed with the rest.

[image: RiverBorder]

The final result looks like this - notice that the shader can survive some deformation (in this case, a couple of bends and a subdivision surface), so long at it is not deformed along the X axis (as that is where the "border" is defined with the Wave Texture). It is still fine to deform along the Y and Z axis, however.

[image: RiverFinal]

Answer (score 0):

If you want an outline at the edges of meshes you could try the layer weight node. Grab Mix Shader Node and plug the the main shader you're using into the first shader input. Then concont whatever shader effect you want the outline to be and plug it into the second shader input. Finally grab the layer weight node and plug it into the 'Fac' input (still in the mix shader node). By adjusting the blend parameter on the layer weight node you should be able to manipulate how much of an outline you're seeing. Note: This may not be as successful on a flat plane, but have you tried adding a small wave modifier to your stream mesh? This way you'll get a more dynamic stream and will also be creating the information for the layer weight mesh to show up. Suggestion: If you make the outline white it may even give you more of those white streaks that looks like frothing water.

As for the reflection, using the principal shader for the first input (into the mix shader) and turning up the metallic parameter might help. Adjusting the roughness after that will affect how sharp the reflection is. To give you the best chance of reflection make sure you're using a nice HDR or in this case (for a non realistic environment) a purpose built lighting set up. Play around with different lights in the scene depending on where the camera viewpoint will be.

Hope this hels.